# How to convert video (in gallery) to NSData? in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I just haven't "info" in Swift imagePickerController so I don't know how get url and convert it to data to send to web-service.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

  var videoDataURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
  var videoFileURL = videoDataURL.filePathURL
  var video = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile("\(videoDataURL)")
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your issue. What is the problem with the "info" parameter in your posted code?

Comment: Cool The posted code work in Swift not swift2 i ask how it work in swift 2 this my function parameter no info in it  "   func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?)"

Comment: In what way doesn't the posted code work in Swift 2? The delegate method in your comment is deprecated. Use the one in your question. Just fix the `info` parameter to be `[String : AnyObject]`.

Comment: Thanks I was wrong it work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Xcode 10 • Swift 4.2 or later**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    if let url = info[.mediaURL] as? URL {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: url, to: documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("videoName.mov"))
            print("movie saved")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Xcode 8.3 • Swift 3.1**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
    let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    if let fileURL =  info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL {
        do {
            try  FileManager.default.moveItem(at: fileURL, to: documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("videoName.mov")
            print("movie saved")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Swift 2**

You should use if let to unwrap your optionals. Also `NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile` was deprecated iOS8. Try using NSData method initializer contentsOfURL:

Note: You need also to change the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo declaration from `[NSObject : AnyObject]` to `[String : AnyObject]`

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let fileURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
        if let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL) {
            print(videoData.length)
        }
    }
}
```

as mentioned by Rob the data can be really large but instead of copying the file you should move the file to the documents folder as follow:

```
let documentsDirectoryURL =  try! NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
if let fileURL =  info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
    do {
        try  NSFileManagerdefaultManager().moveItemAtURL(fileURL, toURL: documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("videoName").URLByAppendingPathExtension("mov"))
        print("movie saved")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of issues:

1. Consider this line:

   ```
   var videoDataURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
   ```

   This does a forced unwrapping of `info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]` (which is bad, because if it was `nil`, the app would crash) and that casts it as an implicitly unwrapped optional `NSURL!`. That doesn't make sense. Just do a conditional unwrapping (and unwrap to a `NSURL`, not a `NSURL!`):

   ```
   if let videoDataURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL { ... }
   ```
2. The next line calls `filePathURL`:

   ```
   var videoFileURL = videoDataURL.filePathURL
   ```

   If you wanted a file URL, you already have one, so no conversion is needed, but instead just use `videoDataURL`. If you really wanted a path, you'd use `path` method:

   ```
   let videoPath = videoDataURL.path
   ```

   Frankly, Apple is trying to shift us away from using string paths, so just use the original `videoDataURL` and avoid the use of both `path` and `filePathURL`.
3. You are using `dataWithContentsOfMappedFile`:

   ```
   var video = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile("\(videoDataURL)")
   ```

   If you really wanted to use `dataWithContentsOfMappedFile`, the proper Swift syntax is:

   ```
   let video = NSData(contentsOfMappedFile: videoPath!)
   ```

   But `dataWithContentsOfMappedFile` deprecated, so you should instead use:

   ```
   let video = try NSData(contentsOfFile: videoPath!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
   ```

   Or, bypassing that `videoPath` altogether, you could:

   ```
   let video3 = try NSData(contentsOfURL: videoDataURL, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
   ```

   Obviously, those `try` renditions should be done within a `do` block with a `catch` block.
4. By the way, as you'll see in all of my above examples, one should use `let` where possible.

--

Quite frankly, I would advise against loading it into a `NSData` at all. Just copy it with `NSFileManager`, which is a more efficient use of memory. If the video is long, it could be quite large, and you should avoid loading the whole thing into memory at any given point in time.

So you could:

```
if let videoDataURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
    do {
        // build your destination URL however you want
        //
        // let tempFolder = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        // let destinationURL = tempFolder.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.mov")

        // or 

        let documents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
        let destinationURL = documents.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.mov")

        // but just copy from the video URL to the destination URL

        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(videoDataURL, toURL: destinationURL)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

If you're uploading this to a web service, you'd then use a `NSURLSessionUploadTask`, using file or stream options. The construction of this request is a separate question, but hopefully you get the idea: With large assets like photos or, especially, videos, don't instantiate a `NSData` with the asset if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: You should also explain how this answer fixes the problem in the question.

Comment: @rmaddy - I was cutting the Gordian knot, but I have modified answer to describe the issues.

Comment: Hi Rob! Is there any way I can read the data in range only and upload to the server. Example: Suppose if I have a video of 1 Gb so first I read 0 - 50 MB and upload to server and then 50 - 100 Mb and upload and so on.

Comment: @FarooqueAzam - Because you’re still dealing with large uploads (50MB each), I’d be inclined to create separate files for each 50MB chunk. E.g. create `InputStream` and start reading in the contents (probably reading in 10-100kb at time), writing to an `OutputStream` that you create for each 50MB chunk. Then you can do file-based uploads (great for background `URLSession`) of those individual files. But that’s beyond the scope of this question, so if you really have further questions, create your own question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

After picking video this method will get called

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("in here")
    if let pickedVideo = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL.rawValue)] as? URL {
            print(pickedVideo)
        do {
            print("Converted")
           // let VideoData = try Data(contentsOf: pickedVideo)
            uploadVideo(VideoData: try Data(contentsOf: pickedVideo), URL: pickedVideo)
            
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the Simple Solution :

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    // Using just the information key value
    if let url = info[.mediaURL] as? URL {
        // Do something with the URL
        print("Media URL : ",url)
        do {
            let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```