# swift video to document directory

Tags: swift, save, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to save video captured with UIImagePicker to a custom folder in app document directory

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    if let fileURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
        if let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL) {
            //save file to doc dir or save NSData into Core Data binary field

        }
    }
}
```

alternatively I can save videoData in Core Data binary field with external storage but after I can't play the video with media player because I can't convert NSData to NSURL.

Comment: Dont load the whole movie data to memory, your app may crash deppending on the file size. Just use file manager move item at url method to move it to the new location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33189238/2303865

Answer (score 4):

Try this for Swift 3

```
    var uniqueVideoID = ""
    var videoURL:NSURL? = NSURL()
    var uniqueID = ""

    //Add this to ViewDidLoad
    uniqueID = NSUUID().UUIDString


    //Getting the path as URL and storing the data in myVideoVarData.
            videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL as NSURL?
        let myVideoVarData = try! Data(contentsOf: videoURL! as URL)

        //Now writeing the data to the temp diroctory.
        let tempPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let tempDocumentsDirectory: AnyObject = tempPath[0] as AnyObject
            uniqueVideoID = uniqueID  + "TEMPVIDEO.MOV"
        let tempDataPath = tempDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(uniqueVideoID) as String
            try? myVideoVarData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: tempDataPath), options: [])

        //Getting the time value of the movie.
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempDataPath)
        let asset = AVAsset(url: fileURL)
        let duration : CMTime = asset.duration
            videoAlertIdVar = duration.value // Control for the runVideoAlert function.

        //Now we remove the data from the temp Document Diroctory.
        do{
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: tempDataPath)
        } catch {
            //Do nothing
        }

        // Cheacking to see if video is under the 18500 (:30 seconds).
        if duration.value <= 18500 {
           yesOrNo = "no" //Control for the button in the mainViewController is hidden or not. The default is "yes"

        //Here we are writing the data to the Document Directory for use later on.
        let docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = docPaths[0] as AnyObject
            uniqueVideoID = uniqueID  + "VIDEO.MOV"
        let docDataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(uniqueVideoID) as String
            try? myVideoVarData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: docDataPath), options: [])
            print("docDataPath under picker ",docDataPath)

        //This creates a thumbnail image.
        let assetImageGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            assetImageGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let time = CMTimeMake(asset.duration.value / 3, asset.duration.timescale)

         //This adds the thumbnail to the imageview.
        if let videoImage = try? assetImageGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil) {
            videoThumbnailOutlet.image = UIImage(cgImage: videoImage)
          }
        }else{
            //Do nothing
   }
```

Play the video

```
    //Note: The _videoData_ is the same as the _uniqueID_
    var videoData = ""

     func play (){

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]

    let videoDataPath = documentsDirectory + "/" + videoData + "VIDEO.MOV"

    let filePathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoDataPath)


    let player = AVPlayer(url: filePathURL)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
    self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Swift 2.2

```
    var uniqueVideoID = ""
    var videoURL: NSURL? = NSURL()
    var uniqueID = ""

    //Add this to ViewDidLoad
    uniqueID = NSUUID().UUIDString

            //Getting the path as URL and storing the data in myVideoVarData.
        videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
        let myVideoVarData = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL!)!

        //Now writeing the data to the temp diroctory.
        let tempPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        let tempDocumentsDirectory: AnyObject = tempPath[0]
            uniqueVideoID = uniqueID  + "TEMPVIDEO.MOV"
        let tempDataPath = tempDocumentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(uniqueVideoID)
            myVideoVarData.writeToFile(tempDataPath, atomically: false)

        //Getting the time value of the movie.
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: tempDataPath)
        let asset = AVAsset(URL: fileURL)
        let duration : CMTime = asset.duration


        //Now we remove the data from the temp Document Diroctory.
        do{
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(tempDataPath)
        } catch {
            //Do nothing
        }

        // Cheacking to see if video is under the 18500 (:30 seconds).
        if duration.value <= 18500 {


        //Here we are writing the data to the Document Directory for use later on.
        let docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = docPaths[0]
            uniqueVideoID = uniqueID  + "VIDEO.MOV"
        let docDataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(uniqueVideoID)
            myVideoVarData.writeToFile(docDataPath, atomically: false)
            print("docDataPath under picker ",docDataPath)

        //This creates a thumbnail image.
        let assetImageGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            assetImageGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let time = CMTimeMake(asset.duration.value / 3, asset.duration.timescale)

         //This adds the thumbnail to the imageview.
        if let videoImage = try? assetImageGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil) {
            videoThumbnailOutlet.image = UIImage(CGImage: videoImage)
          }
        }else{
            //Do nothing
   }
```

Now play the video.

```
    //Note: The _videoData_ is the same as the _uniqueID_
    var videoData = ""


    func play (){

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]

    let videoDataPath = documentsDirectory + "/" + videoData + "VIDEO.MOV"

    let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(videoDataPath)


    let player = AVPlayer(URL: filePathURL)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
    self.presentViewController(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()


    }
    }
```