# Swift get NSData of a video from photos library

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata, nsurl

Im using UIImagePickerController to select a video from my library. I need to extract the NSData of my video file. Im using the following operation to select a video from my library but my data appears to be nil however my AVPlayer plays the video from the resulting NSURL so I know problem is not with the NSURL. How can I extract the NSData of my selected video file?

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let fileURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL!

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
    print(data)

    player = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189012/swift2-how-to-convert-video-in-gallary-to-nsdata-in-swift-2

Comment: I have already seen it, did not solve my problem...

Answer (score 9):

Try changing UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL to

> *UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL*

Instead of let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL)

> *let video3 = try NSData(contentsOfURL: videoDataURL, options:
>   .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)*

Comment: @NaciKurdoglu glad it helped you :) also please mark it as correct.

Comment: Helpful answer. Thanks @Arsalan