# Is there something for Representation of NSData as MOV

Tags: swift, video, nsdata

I can submit photos to my restkit api using **UIImageJpegRepresentation** as in

```
formData?.appendPartWithFileData(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo as UIImage, compression as CGFloat), name: "photo", fileName: "photo.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            })
```

Is there something similar for submitting video?

```
formData?.appendPartWithFileData(movieNSData, name: "video_binary", fileName: "video.mov", mimeType: "video/mov")
```

does not seem to work.

Comment: Your issue is to convert a video.mov into a `NSData` object? Where is that video.mov? Somewhere in your app? Somewhere in Photos.app ?

Comment: The video is taken from an UIImagePicker

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189012/swift2-how-to-convert-video-in-gallary-to-nsdata-in-swift-2 ?