# UIImagePickerController image nil for .mov files

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using an `UIImagePickerController`, which is working fine for images made with the iPhone camera, but `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` is always `nil` for movies (.mov) also created with the iPhone camera.

The picker is presented here:

```
self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
if let mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary) {
    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
}
self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here the simple `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` implementation:

```
extension MyTableViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
        // ...
        print(info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]) 
            // prints nil
        print(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]) 
            // prints nil for .mov files
        print(info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]) 
            // prints the correct file url in file://var/.../*.mov
}
```

I am on a real device, iOS11.2.

Comment: What it is returning nil? Of course `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` and  `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` will always be nil for movies. What's wrong with getting the data from the url?

Comment: @LeoDabus: `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] == nil`

Comment: Do you need a thumbnail for the movie file? Thats a different question.

Comment: @LeoDabus: No. I want to get the movie. The question is: why is it nil? Is it intended to be like this and I do not understand it correctly? All example code I found uses it and assumes it is not nil for movies.

Comment: SO you need to get a frame from your movie. You will need to create a AVURLAsset using that url. `AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)`. Then use it to create a image generator `AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: yourUrlAsset)` and use copyCGImage method to fetch a frame `CGImage` from it.

Comment: @LeoDabus: thank you. That is a very good hint. But it is not the question. Is it intended to be like this and I do not understand it correctly? All example code I found uses it and assumes it is not nil for movies.

Comment: How would you expect a movie to be represented as an `UIImage`
? You need to choose which frame you will grab from it.

Comment: What you are saying totally makes sense :-). But actually I need to get the data of the video. Probably I am asking stupid questions. Totally tired.

Comment: All you need it is the url. You don't need to load all its data into memory.

Comment: Yes, I do need the data. That is required for my task. I have to send it to another device.

Comment: I mean to create the thumbnail. Btw there is a limit size when attaching data to an email.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33189012/2303865

Comment: Thanks! That's what I could not think of. I thought that can not work when reaching out of the sandbox and did not even try.